# divide and conquer method for linker

Tags: c++, linker, ld

I have multiple files (>300 object files), whose need in linking with "ld" command. 
Now, I waste a lot of time, while I wait linking process will be done (and this process not always will be successful).

I have next question: can I use "divide and conquer" method for linking, e.g. link every pair object files (for example objfile1.o and objfile2.o) in single object file (for example objfile1-2.o). After it apply this scheme for every pair of objects.
Further, link every pair objects, that were got on previous stage, and so on.
Finally, link a few objects (may be pair) in one result file.

Can I use this scheme for linking (with ld)?

Comment: If such a thing were possible/actually faster, I'd guess most popular compilers would already implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary splitting is probably not a good idea, but you likely
can improve link times by breaking the application up into
several shared objects, and linking against those.  When linking
against a shared object, the linker doesn't have to actually
copy the data into the executable, but only check that the
shared object does define the needed symbols.

Still, 300 object files is not a lot, and shouldn't slow things
down that much, ad least with a modern system, at least if
they're on a local drive.  (Back in the old days, when
everything was on a remote drive, we used to set up our
makefiles so that the link phase would run on the file server,
rather than on our local machine.  This could speed things up by
a factor of 10 or more.)

Comment: +1 for shared libraries, a safe way to avoid huge linking times while reusing code

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you approach it, when linking the final executable, the linker has to peruse the *whole* list of contents. Any intermediate "staging" of the linking process will only *increase* the runtime.

Picture it:

- object1.o contains foo(), bar()
- object2.o contains fiddle(), lee()
- main.o contains main(), which calls the above functions

When you're linking, the linker *will* need to link the functions together, regardless of whether they are in one file or two files.

Comment: This is only partially true.  When linking against a `.so`, the linker only has to scan parts of the `.so`, to see if the symbols are defined.  When linking against a `.o`, the linker must copy the entire file data (object code and symbol tables) into the file it is building, which requires significantly more time.  (When linking against an `.a`, of course, the linker must first read enough to determine which of the constituant `.o` it needs, and then process those as above.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: OP didn't mention linking against an `.so`, but linking `.o` *together*, which indicates linking-to-executable (or, actually, linking-to-so). I decided not to complicate matters. ;-)

Comment: Even when linking against multiple `.o` files, partial linking *can* save time. Much of the linker time is spent applying relocations, and the number of relocations that the linker has to process can be greatly reduced by linking objects that refer to each other into a single object with `ld -r`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I am not convinced that would save anything. For one, linking the various .o files together into a single object with `ld -r` is likely to take about as long as linking them all together into the executable in the first place (which you would *still* have to do). Two, you deny the linker the opportunity to leave unused .o contents aside, resulting in a full-size binary even if not all the code is actually required.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not a suggested way. However, you may create static or shared library for portions and link with the shared library for multiple executables, if any linked with the shared library. That will surely take some time less than monolithic linking for every executable without any overlap.

Comment: Static libraries will probably not help with his problem, and may make it worse.